# How to discuss the convergence and divergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\ln n!}{n^{\alpha}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We need to discuss how the convergence(including **conditional** convergence and **absolute** convergence) and divergence of series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\ln n!}{n^{\alpha}}$ will change when $\alpha$ changes.

**In my opinion**, note that $\ln n!=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln i$, so the above series will be transformed into a double summation, but this obviously increases the complexity, I thought about it for a long time and didn't make any progress, could someone give me some ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Note revision of answer to clarify, particularly for absolute convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling approximation: $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n$.  Take logs and sum terms $\approx (-1)^n( \frac{\ln(\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n^\alpha}+\frac{ln(n)-ln(e)}{n^{\alpha-1}})$.
The key to the convergence question is the behavior of $(-1)^n\frac{ln(n)}{n^{\alpha-1}}$ for large $n$. There are two tests which apply, ratio test and integral test.  The ratio test with alternating sign gives conditional convergence for $\alpha \gt 1$ and divergence for $\alpha \le 1$.  The integral test gives absolute convergence for $\alpha \gt 2$ only.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use the inequalities
$$
\frac{x}{1+x} \leq \ln (1+x) \leq x \quad \text { for } x>-1
$$
to conclude that
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left|(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\cdot \frac{n!-1}{n!}\right|
\leq 
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left|(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\cdot \ln (n!)\right|
\leq 
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left|(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\cdot (n!)\right|
$$